# how to add label to the chart created using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

hello all i am able to display the chart but i need to add labels to the chart the labels are given below but i am not able to display it in the chart any help pls thanks in advance

```js
         
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var lastend = 0;
 
 var data = [20,40]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
 var labels = ["leavebalance", "leaveavailability"];
 var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
 var myColor = ['red','green']; // Colors of each slice
     
 for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
   myTotal += data[e];
      
 }
 //alert(myTotal);

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
   //ctx.fillText(labels[i]);
   //ctx.fillText = labels[i];
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   // Arc Parameters: x, y, radius, startingAngle (radians), endingAngle (radians), antiClockwise (boolean)
   ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal)), false);
   ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   ctx.fill();
   lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal);
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="150" >
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not work because it depends on an external webservice. Please providing an example which can be tested. I also don't even see an attempt to draw the labels in the code you posted. What did you try? Are you just asking [how to draw text on a canvas](http://html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-text.php)?

Comment: @Philipp i have updated my question .i want labels for the two data 20,40

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Here's one way to apply labels to each wedge in a pie chart:**

- Calculate the middle angle between the starting & ending angles for each wedge in the pie.
- Calculate the [x,y] that is on the middle angle and near the circumference.
- Set `textAlign` & `textBaseline` so drawn text is centered on the calculated [x,y].
- Draw the label at the calculated [x,y] `fillText('20',x,y)`

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.font = '12px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myColor = ['red','green','blue'];
var myData = [25,35,40];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 100;

pieChart(myData, myColor);

function pieChart(data, colors) {

  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i];
  }

  var sweeps = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sweeps.push(data[i] / total * PI2);
  }

  var accumAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
    drawWedge(accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], colors[i], data[i]);
    accumAngle += sweeps[i];
  }


}

function drawWedge(startAngle, endAngle, fill, label) {

  // draw the wedge
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = fill;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw the label
  var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
  var labelRadius = radius * .75;
  var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
  var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText(label, x, y);

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 10px;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: how to add my labels here var labels("XXX","yyy","ZZZ) instead of the values 25,35,40

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan, Simple! Just send `XXX` in as the `label` argument to drawWedge`.  :-)